# Recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm trying to reproduce the library example provided by Netbeans. In other words, I made an exact copy of this library, but instead using Netbeans samples I created files myself.

Here's what I mean (`hello4lib` is from samples, `myLib` is manually created)

[image]

The problem is that `myLib` build fails, but `hello4lib` doesn't. It doesn't make any sense, because they are the same (makefiles are identical too). What am I missing?

Comment: I am really not sure about that, but have you tried to move .cc file into the same directory of .h file? And why do you use .cc file and not .cpp or .c file?

Comment: KorelK, hey! The header and source files are in the same directory. I've tried using .cpp extension and it didn't work either, so I left it as in the example library (.cc)

Comment: @KorelK, now the `"Unable to resolve identifier"` error is gone. It just disapeared for no apparent reason and the build fails anyway. Updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by removing whitespaces from the path.

Path before: `/home/manid/MEGAsync/Dev/Linux (c, c++)/libraries/myLib/myLib.h`

Path after: `/home/manid/MEGAsync/Dev/Linux/libraries/myLib/myLib.h`